# How can the Dropbox API alert when a token is received?

Tags: android, dropbox, access-token, dropbox-api

I am able to log in and do export/import from my Android app using the v2 Dropbox API. The only problem is on first run when a token is requested and the Dropbox app/website is launched - I have to run Auth.startOAuth2Authentication at least twice with a pause in between to be able to read the token with Auth.getOAuth2Token.

Is there anyway to wait() and get notified when startOAuth2Authentication returns after acquiring a token?

```
   Auth.startOAuth2Authentication(this, getString(R.string.app_key));
   //wait for response, retry, or time out and finish
   String accessToken = Auth.getOAuth2Token();
   prefs.edit().putString(ACCESS_TOKEN, accessToken).commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't call `startOAuth2Authentication` twice, and you shouldn't call `getOAuth2Token` immediately after calling `startOAuth2Authentication`.

You should start the flow by calling `startOAuth2Authentication` as shown in the example here:

https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java/blob/master/examples/android/src/main/java/com/dropbox/core/examples/android/UserActivity.java#L36

And then you should complete the flow by calling `getOAuth2Token` later in `onResume` as shown in the example here:

https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java/blob/master/examples/android/src/main/java/com/dropbox/core/examples/android/DropboxActivity.java#L22

Comment: I meant I'm calling it twice because i'm tapping the button twice after waiting a bit... Otherwise that code won't work (and obviously is not good)

Comment: startOAuth2Authentication is at in onStart. Even if getOAuth2Token is in onResume, it could still mean only a fraction of a second have passed and it's not enough to get the token back. I don't understand what difference it will make. Could you clarify?

Comment: Calling `startOAuth2Authentication` initiates the manual user app authorization flow. When that is called, you should be sent either to the Dropbox web site or the official Dropbox Android app (if installed). There, the user has the option to authorize the app. Once they do so, they will be sent back to your app, triggering `onResume` where `getOAuth2Token` will return the access token. That will take an undetermined amount of time, since it depends on user action, and your app doesn't need to know how long it takes.

Comment: Ok I think I understand now. So Dropbox will only send me back to my app when the token was already generated and available when I'll call getOAuth2Token nex.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example for implementing the Dropbox Android API:
https://www.sitepoint.com/adding-the-dropbox-api-to-an-android-app/

Now, to get to the point of your question, you will not be able to get a toke immediately after `Auth.startOAuth2Authentication(this, getString(R.string.app_key));` is called. After you call this method, the Dropbox login activity is shown, and you can get the token only after the user logs in (which is in no way immediate, and you have no way of telling how long it will take).
After the user logs in successfully your activity will be resumed, and you can see in the example from the tutorial that the Activity's `onResume` method is overridden a check is performed in there.

I will copy below the `LoginActivity` from this tutorial. It should be easy enough to start from here:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        Button SignInButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
        SignInButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Auth.startOAuth2Authentication(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.APP_KEY));
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getAccessToken();
    }

    public void getAccessToken() {
        String accessToken = Auth.getOAuth2Token(); //generate Access Token
        if (accessToken != null) {
            //Store accessToken in SharedPreferences
            SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("com.example.valdio.dropboxintegration", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            prefs.edit().putString("access-token", accessToken).apply();

            //Proceed to MainActivity
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```